# windows ansible playbook to execute VBscript

Tags: ansible

We do have a requirement to execute a VBscript.vbs in windows machine. Once it executes, it generates a GUI pop-up window where we put an input as  log  which scans and generates the packages installed on the server in a logfile.  We need to automate it using ansible playbook as we can use win_command or win_shell to execute that script but how can we pass the input arguments in the playbook and so once the script completes it generates the log file ? Please guide me with hint... thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is the requirement to use Ansible to manage Windows machines?
Ansible can work with Windows, but Windows doesn't play well with Ansible.

Perhaps a more fitting solution would be to use Powershell.

To answer your question:

> It generates a GUI pop-up window where we put an input as log. [...]
> How can we pass the input arguments in the playbook?

You can't let Ansible fill stuff in on a GUI. You should edit the .vbs script to take input from the command line or to read configuration from a file. Then you can simply use the [win_shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_shell_module.html) command. Example:

```yaml
- hosts: windows_1
  tasks:
    - name: execute script
      win_shell: C:/path.vbs argument1 argument2
      register: execution_of_script

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ execution_of_script }}"
```

Comment: Awesome man. It works. Actually, i tried in powershell in the windows client before i execute through playbook. When i try calling  vbs with argument it executes and next pop-up for me to press OK to create log. I hope win_shell will take care with that too without stuck in OK screen, else need to check any option like /s or something. Let me try through playbook. thanks again..